# Output of Speech Recognition (Python)

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, sys

I am working on a project with speech recognition module and due to my different language, I want to save on text file so I can read and have proper output; but when I tried sys module to save the file it came with some errors. If you help me to fix this I`ll be appreciate
This is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import sys

r = sr.Recognizer()
print('How can I help you?')
def my_first_sr():
    while True:
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as mic:
                r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic)
                audio = r.listen(mic)
                text = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'fa-IR')
            print(text)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print('I didn`t understand!')

        except sr.RequestError:
            print('Sorry my service is down')


my_first_sr()
output = open('Speech Recognition.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = output
print(text)
output.close()
```

Comment: Can't you just `open` the file instead of `print`ing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the text to the file output:

```
import speech_recognition as sr 

r = sr.Recognizer()
print('How can I help you?')
def my_first_sr():
    while True:
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as mic:
                r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic)
                audio = r.listen(mic)
                text = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'fa-IR')

            print(text)

            output = open('Speech Recognition.txt', 'w')
            output.write(text)#Write the text to the file
            output.close()

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print('I didn`t understand!')

        except sr.RequestError:
            print('Sorry my service is down')


my_first_sr()
```